# In an ERD, can a foreign key of a table refer to the primary key of the table on other the side of of an intermediate table without a new relation

Tags: sql, database, pgadmin, erd

Imagine an ERD with a table of **Employees** (employee_id as primary key), **Tasks** (employee_id, project_id as composite primary key and foreign keys), **Projects** (project_id as primary key). Tasks is the intermediate table of Projects and Employees.

Employees is in a relationship with Tasks, Tasks is in a relationship with Employees and Projects, Projects is in a relationship with Tasks.

Now, imagine without drawing an additional relationship between Projects and Employees, I put a foreign key called e_id in Projects that refers to employee_id of Employees.

Am I allowed to do this **without drawing an additional relationship**, I wouldn't think so.
I mean they're connected through an intermediate table, but I don't think it's legal to do that in an ERD diagram and that really brings me **to my question sub-question**:

**In an ERD Diagram can a foreign key in a table only refer to a primary key in a different table** (or same if recursive) **if those two tables have a drawn relationship** (with this I mean a line drawn from one table to the other without first making a stop through a intermediate table)

I really hope my question is clear

Have an amazing day!

Comment: _"In an ERD Diagram can a foreign key in a table only refer to a primary key in a different table..."_ - are you aware that foreign-keys can **also** reference `UNIQUE KEY` constraints - not just `PRIMARY KEY` constraints?

Comment: No, I was not, but I'm only focussing very simplified on ERD's, nevertheless, if I'm right, a unique key is just a primary key that can accept NULL as its value. Really what I need to know is if two tables should always have a drawn relationship (without intermediate table) when they're paired with foreign and primary key

Comment: _"if I'm right, a unique key is just a primary key that can accept NULL as its value."_ - no, that is entirely incorrect, sorry (`UNIQUE KEY` constraints cannot contain `NULL`, and it's also known as a _secondary key_, not "just a primary key").

Comment: If you're asking about what notation or idioms are permissable in a diagram or allowed by some spec then you need to tell us which ER diagram standard or system you want to conform to (and please don't say UML... it needs to die) - if you're not following any specific standard then you have total freedom to put whatever you want so-long as it means something to you - in which case why post this question to SO?

Comment: _"can a foreign key of a table refer to the primary key of the table on other the side of of an intermediate table without a new relation"_ - as an aside, [a "relation" is **not** a "relationship"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(database)). A "relation" is actually a `TABLE`,`VIEW`, derived-table or CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Imagine an ERD with a table of `Employees` (`employee_id` as primary key), `Tasks` (`employee_id`, `project_id` as composite primary key and foreign keys), Projects (`project_id` as primary key). `Tasks` is the intermediate table of `Projects` and `Employees`.
>
> - `Employees` is in a relationship with `Tasks`.
> - `Tasks` is in a relationship with `Employees` and `Projects`
> - `Projects` is in a relationship with `Tasks`.

You mean like this?

[image]

> Now, imagine without drawing an additional relationship between `Projects` and `Employees`, I put a foreign key called `e_id` in `Projects` that refers to `employee_id` of `Employees`.
>
> Am I allowed to do this without drawing an additional relationship?

Too late: *you already have* defined this new relationship: consider that an ER "relationship" **is a** `FOREIGN KEY` constraint, and vice-versa.

The act of adding a foreign-key from `Projects.e_id` to `Employees_employee_id` *also means* you're adding a new relationship between the Project and Employee entities.

...like so:

[image]

> I wouldn't think so. I mean they're connected through an intermediate table, but I don't think it's legal to do that in an ERD diagram and that really brings me to my question sub-question

- *"I mean they're connected through an intermediate table"* - when you say "intermediate table" I assume you're referring to many-to-many linking tables,  but consider...

  - ...in a many-to-many relationship in an ER diagram, the linking-table *is not an entity*.
  - The `Tasks` table **is** its own Entity (despite the `Tasks` table not yet having any data attributes/plain-ol-data-columns. Furthermore the fact it's called "`Tasks`" (a noun) also strongly-hints that it's its own Entity.
  - ...and nothing stops any entity from having a relationship with any other entity - unless you have some pressing domain-rules against it in some cases.

> In an ERD Diagram can a foreign key in a table only refer to a primary key in a different table (or same if recursive) if those two tables have a drawn relationship (with this I mean a line drawn from one table to the other without first making a stop through a intermediate table)

<sub>"ERD Diagram"? I must report you to the Department of Redundancy Department!</sub>

To repeat my earlier point: a "drawn relationship" or "line drawn" in an ER diagram **represents** a foreign-key constraint between those two tables. Drawing a line on a piece of paper is *not* a prerequisite for implementing a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint.

(Also, foreign-keys can also reference secondary-keys (aka `UNIQUE KEY`), not just `PRIMARY KEY` constraints, ofc).